# Choosing 6 questions from 2 group.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have two groups $A$ and $B$ such that each contain 5 question. Now 2 questions are mandatory to attempt from each group. How can one choose 6 questions?

My solution -
first chose 2,2 manditory question from both group and then either 2 from first group or second. Or we could chose first manditory questions and then then one - one from each from both group
$$\binom{5}{2}*\binom{5}{2}*\binom{3}{2}*2  + \binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1} $$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into **disjoint** cases, count the number of options for each case and add up the results:

- Number of ways to choose $2$ questions from A and $4$ questions from B: $\binom52\cdot\binom54=50$
- Number of ways to choose $3$ questions from A and $3$ questions from B: $\binom53\cdot\binom53=100$
- Number of ways to choose $4$ questions from A and $2$ questions from B: $\binom54\cdot\binom52=50$

Hence the total number of ways to choose questions is $50+100+50=200$.